# PowerPoint 2010 - Electrocardiogram -like chart

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, charts

I need to make a chart in PowerPoint (PowerPoint 2010) that is like an electrocardiogram, actually is a chromatogram, I'm trying with line charts but I can't get the "peaks" of the line. I mean, in a normal line chart I get the peaks but not the curved line, if I change the line to a smoothed one I loose the peaks.

Any ideas?

**Chart that I need to re-create in PowerPoint:**
[image]

**Peaks I can't recreate:**
[image]

**PPT Normal Line Chart:**
[image]

**PPT Smoothed Line Chart:**
[image]

**PPT from normal to smoothed line:**
[image]

**Chart values**

[image]

Comment: Do you know about this software called gnuplot - may be that can help you and you can embed the result of gnuplot on power point. Or do you intend to change the data during presentation and show updates from power point?

Comment: If you are trying to replicate the chromatagram, I can see a couple of problems. 1) you are missing the real Y values.  The displayed numbers are the X locations where the peaks occur.  The Y values define the height at those locations (may need to interpolate from the original). 2) The pictured peaks are much narrower.  You would need to play with the inflection points and maybe add a few points to better define the shape of the rise and fall (interpolate from the picture). 3) The un-smoothed line is a better representation. 4) Your animations are really cool.

Comment: @Prasanna tanks for the tip, I'll try it in the weekend. The thing is that this is for a client and he wants/ needs to be able to change the data in the future by himself. If this was a one thing chart, I'll deal with it in Illustrator or similar and done.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks for the anwser. 1) is a coincidence, but the displayed numbers are the Y values! (I just added a screenshot of the chart values) 2) & 3) Yes I also think that the best workaround would be the straight line chart and that I would have to play with the values around the peak and around the curves at the bottom 4) I used a software called ScreenToGif - https://screentogif.codeplex.com/ very usefull for explaining things :D

Comment: The displayed numbers are the Y values on the charts you created, but not on the original you're trying to copy.  The first peak is about 20000, the second about 5000, and the third about 80000.  If you need something that can be replicated when the data changes, you will probably need to create generic formulas for a collection of points for given X,Y values that define the general shape of a peak.  Looks like there is a minimum width at the base and then the base is a function of the height.  After a fixed radius at the base, it looks like a straight line to the peak.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes I was trying something like you mention, some sort of formula to get the values around the peak, using a simple line chart, and I'm getting some acceptable results, thanks! I'll edit the question later